# Free up cassandra table that has secondary index

Tags: cassandra

We are using a Cassandra to develop our application and we use a secondary index in one of our table for faster performance. As of now in our production, we saw a growing disk space on the table that has secondary index on it. It becomes a problem on us since we have a lot of data need to store.  As a result, we would like to reduce the disk space on that table.

We are thinking following to recreate the table without secondary index and repopulate the data. However, this is a time consuming task.

Do you have any suggestion on how to reduce the disk space size on the table that has secondary index?

Thanks

cassio

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the index. What I'm really curious is did you actually gain performance with secondary indexes as they are mostly used to enable query patterns with certain performance penalty instead of building another denormalized table to serve the query directly. Are you sure its the secondary indexes that are growing your data size? Do you have leftover snapshots or something like that?

Comment: The secondary index is more convenience over than performance gain. We did check the snapshots using nodetool cfstats and ensure there is no snapshot created and space taken by the secondary index table takes around 30% more than the table without secondary index.  From what I see, the secondary index did create hidden table and take more space.  As you suggested, we may drop the index and recreate the table without the secondary index. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to recreate the table. Just drop the index.